# Why do rounded cornes of a window look weird in a composite manager?

Tags: linux, window, compositing

I'm trying to add some fancy stuff to my desktop, and the thing that I'm dealing with now is setting shades to all windows. I'm using compton composite manager, and everything is fine, but just look at the following images:
[image]

If a window has normal corners, everything is ok, but when I'm trying to round them, the strange effect occurs.

I'm using debian testing disto, standalone openbox, and nvidia graphic (7600GT) + proprietary drives. I have installed the following packages:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i mesa
ii  glx-alternative-mesa                                        0.4.1                                        amd64        allows the selection of MESA as GLX provider
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                                          9.2.2-1                                      amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64                                  9.2.2-1                                      amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- hardware drivers
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                                       9.2.2-1                                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                                       9.2.2-1                                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                                         9.2.2-1                                      amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                                          9.0.0-2                                      amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libopenvg1-mesa:amd64                                       9.2.2-1                                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenVG API -- runtime
ii  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64                                     0~git20121227-2                              amd64        Texture compression library for Mesa
ii  mesa-utils                                                  8.1.0-2                                      amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
$ dpkg -l | grep -i xorg
ii  xorg                                                        1:7.7+4                                      amd64        X.Org X Window System
ii  xorg-docs-core                                              1:1.7-1                                      all          Core documentation for the X.org X Window System
ii  xserver-xorg                                                1:7.7+4                                      amd64        X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core                                           2:1.14.3-5                                   amd64        Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-all                                      1:7.7+4                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev                                    1:2.8.2-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- evdev input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-mouse                                    1:1.9.0-1+b1                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- mouse input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics                                1.7.1-2+b1                                   amd64        Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse                                  1:13.0.0-1+b1                                amd64        X.Org X server -- VMMouse input driver to use with VMWare
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all                                      1:7.7+4                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                                      1:7.2.0-1+b2                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus                                   1:1.5.2-1+b1                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                                    1:0.4.4-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                                    2:2.21.15-1+b2                               amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64                                   6.9.4-1+b1                                   amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mga                                      1:1.6.2-1+b1                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting                              0.8.1-1                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Generic modesetting driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic                                 1:1.2.8-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                                  1:1.0.10-1                                   amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx                      304.116-2                                    amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver (304xx legacy version)
ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome                               1:0.3.3-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                                      0.1.0-2.1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128                                     6.9.1-1                                      amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                                   1:7.2.0-1+b2                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage                                   1:2.3.7-2                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion                            1:1.7.7-2                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb                                   1:0.9.6-2                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx                                     1:1.4.5-1                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident                                  1:1.3.6-2                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                                     1:2.3.3-1+b1                                 amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                                   1:13.0.1-2                                   amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver

$ dpkg -l | grep -i compton
ii  compton                                                     0.1~beta2-1                                  amd64        compositor for X11, based on xcompmgr

$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  glx-alternative-nvidia                                      0.4.1                                        amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libgl1-nvidia-legacy-304xx-glx:amd64                        304.116-2                                    amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL libraries (304xx legacy version)
ii  nvclock-gtk                                                 0.8b4+cvs20100914-5                          amd64        Overclock an NVIDIA card (GTK+ interface)
ii  nvidia-detect                                               319.76-1                                     amd64        NVIDIA GPU detection utility
ii  nvidia-installer-cleanup                                    20131102+1                                   amd64        cleanup after driver installation with the nvidia-installer
ii  nvidia-kernel-common                                        20131102+1                                   amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module support files
ii  nvidia-legacy-304xx-alternative                             304.116-2                                    amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver                                  304.116-2                                    amd64        NVIDIA metapackage (304xx legacy version)
ii  nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms                             304.116-2                                    amd64        NVIDIA binary kernel module DKMS source (304xx legacy version)
ii  nvidia-settings-legacy-304xx                                304.116-1                                    amd64        tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver (304xx legacy version)
ii  nvidia-support                                              20131102+1                                   amd64        NVIDIA binary graphics driver support files
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx                      304.116-2                                    amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver (304xx legacy version)
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux morfikownia 3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.10-1 (2013-12-04) x86_64 GNU/Linu
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Not enough info. Without being able to reproduce the exact issue you're seeing, it's impossible to root cause it. Could be hardware-specific. Could be specific to the version of compton, Xorg, Linux, Mesa, etc. that you're using. Or it might be a genuine bug. To be able to reproduce it, you'd have to give all your details (hardware, software versions, etc).

Comment: Updated. Do you need anything else?

Comment: whatever is doing the shading doesnt recognize the alpha channel... probably nothing you can do about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the compton config file, and there was something like this:

```
clear-shadow = true;        # Zero the part of the shadow's mask behind the window (experimental).
```

Experimental you say? So, I set this to false, and now I have pretty nice rounded windows with shades:

[image]

There's also another way to fix the problem. You can set the following options in compton's config:

```
clear-shadow = true;
shadow-ignore-shaped = flase;
```